# Failed to start The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager

Tags: php, ubuntu

i have problem with `php7`
when i run this command i get the error

> sudo systemctl status php7.0-fpm.service

this output:

```
   ● php7.0-fpm.service - The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since سه<U+200C>شنبه 2016-06-28 17:58:08 IRDT; 4min 27s ago
     Docs: man:php-fpm7.0(8)
  Process: 14328 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 14328 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

ژوئن 28 17:58:08 khonok158 systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
ژوئن 28 17:58:08 khonok158 systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
ژوئن 28 17:58:08 khonok158 systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
ژوئن 28 17:58:08 khonok158 systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: Unit entered failed state.
ژوئن 28 17:58:08 khonok158 systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: What is in your configuration `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf`?

Comment: i delete the folder of 7.0 :D @E_p

Comment: That would do it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably must do this

```
apt-get install --reinstall php
systemctl start php7.0-fpm
systemctl enable php7.0-fpm
systemctl restart apache2
```

for me it works.

```
root@micro:~# systemctl status php7.0-fpm.service
? php7.0-fpm.service - The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-11-27 06:46:40 CET; 1 weeks 1 days ago
     Docs: man:php-fpm7.0(8)
 Main PID: 508 (php-fpm7.0)
   Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 2, Requests: 5736, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/sec"
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/php7.0-fpm.service
           tq508 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
           tq755 php-fpm: pool www
           mq756 php-fpm: pool www
```

Comment: Didnt worked ... I get "Failed to start The PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager"

Answer (score 2):

In my case, previous php7.2-fpm configuration cause problem:

so i deleted directory, and reinstall solve the problem.

(if this is not first time, then backup below php fpm configuration)

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/php/7.2/fpm/
```

Answer (score 2):

I had upgraded the PHP version form 7.1 to 7.3.
I had to kill the running PHP fpm process of 7.1 first before initiating 7.3

Get the process id from the following command:

```
ps -ef | grep PHP
```

Kill the process:

```
kill -9 < pid >
```

Start the PHP:

```
/etc/init.d/php7.3-fpm start
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this problem is quickly. You must check configuration php-fpm and remove error. Then save the configuration and restart service.

Step 1.
Check config php-fpm.

```
sudo php7.2-fpm -t
```

Step 2.

```
Fix configuration errors & again check config.
```

Step 3.
Restart php-fpm service.

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm
```

That`s all

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Fedora 33. I simply uninstalled php and httpd

```
sudo dnf remove httpd
sudo dnf remove php

sudo dnf install php
sudo dnf install http
```

This solved  my issue